# Media queries not changing as intended

Tags: css

I'm using media queries to control the 'margin-top' and 'zoom' CSS properties for some elements, but from some reason its not working as intended.

Those are my CSS media queries:

```
/* (1440x900) WXGA+ Display */
@media  screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
    .multipleVendors {
        zoom: 0.85;
    }
    .searcher {
        zoom: 0.90;
        margin-top:100px;
    }
}


/* (1920x1080) Full HD Display */
@media  screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .multipleVendors {
        zoom: 0.85;
    }
    .searcher {
        zoom: 0.90;
        margin-top:150px;
    }
}
```

My current screen resolution 1920x1080 and its working great (using that custom CSS query) but when I change my screen resolution to 1440x900 its ignore my custom CSS query and still using the 1920x1080 one.

Any idea how to solve this issue? what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second media query is overriding the first due to the cascading nature of CSS. It should work if you just change the order of declarations.

```
/* (1920x1080) Full HD Display */
@media  screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .multipleVendors {
        zoom: 0.85;
    }
    .searcher {
        zoom: 0.90;
        margin-top:150px;
    }
} 

/* (1440x900) WXGA+ Display */
@media  screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
    .multipleVendors {
        zoom: 0.85;
    }
    .searcher {
        zoom: 0.90;
        margin-top:100px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving only the max width, u can mention it in some range. It will helpful in creating the web page for the specific devices and also it wont override your styles.

```
  /* (1440x900) WXGA+ Display */
@media  screen (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
    .multipleVendors {
        zoom: 0.85;
    }
    .searcher {
        zoom: 0.90;
        margin-top:100px;
    }
}


/* (1920x1080) Full HD Display */
@media  screen (min-width: 1441px)and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .multipleVendors {
        zoom: 0.85;
    }
    .searcher {
        zoom: 0.90;
        margin-top:150px;
    }
}
```